# what does .match return?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering what .match returns - the matched characters or a bool?

```
function feinNoRepeat(sender, args)
{
    fein = '11-1111111';
    atchThis = fein.replace("-","");
    rptRegex = '\b(\d)\1+\b';
    //would I compare it this way or would I ask if it's true or false?
    if (matchThis.match(rptRegex) = matchThis) 
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If only there were some way to find out...

Comment: With the current syntax, it'll be an error.

Comment: This issue is mysterious.

Comment: FYI: [string.match docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: this was a really stupid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the DOCS on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

### Syntax

```
var array = string.match(regexp);
```

## Parameters

**regexp**

A regular expression object. If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj).

## Description

If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the same result as regexp.exec(string).

If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matches. If there were no matches, the method returns null.

The returned Array has an extra input property, which contains the regexp that generated it as a result. In addition, it has an index property, which represents the zero-based index of the match in the string.

---

### What you want to do

What you really want is [regularExpression.test(string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) if you want a true or false value

```
if (rptRegex.test(matchThis)) {  //notice it is the regular expression being acted on, not the string
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

It would also work with match since the result of match can be tested for a truthy value.

```
if (matchThis.match(rptRegex)) {
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

It is still better to use test and not match

Answer (score 0):

An array of the matched group values